# ¿Es posible pasar un Json por GET?

Tags: json, url, get

¿Me gustaría saber si es posible pasar un **JSON** por **GET**? y de ser posible, me gustaría saber cómo?

Comment: Hola, Alberto. ¿Qué has investigado hasta ahora? ¿Que has sacado en claro? ¿Probaste algo? De ser asi, ¿qué errores has tenido? Mira [ask], [help/on-topic] y [mcve] para mejorar esta y futuras preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: ¿con cuál lenguaje?

Comment: Como poder, se puede añadir a la URL como un parámetro

Answer (score 1):

Es con C#, pero ya comprobé que si es posible, el caso específico es el siguiente:
En JavaScript tengo el siguiente JSON

```
            var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
            var empresaId = $("#empresaId").val();
            var visitanteId = $("#visitanteId").val();
            var anfitrionId = $("#anfitrionId").val();
            var usuarioId = $("#usuarioId").val();
            var parametros = {
                "UsuarioId": usuarioId,
                "Fecha": fecha,
                "EmpresaId": empresaId,
                "AnfitrionId": anfitrionId,
                "VisitanteId": visitanteId
            }
```

Luego lo envío a un controlador de esta forma:

```
location.href = "../Reportes/ReportTemplate?ReportName=ProgramacionVisitas&ReportParameters=" + parametros;
```

En el controlador lo recibo así:

```
public ActionResult ReportTemplate(string ReportName , string ReportParameters)
{
}
```

Ya lo siguiente sería hacer uso de este JSON que llega como un string.

Comment: **La pregunta no indica que esto sea en C#** Recuerda "No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que  son inciertas o requieren demasiada orientación para que puedas contestarla completamente. Tienes suficiente reputación para haber dejado un comentario en lugar de como una respuesta. Lee [answer] para más información."